# Taking the address of a function from within that function

Tags: c, language-lawyer

First, the question: Is there any reason you can't take the address of a function from within that function?

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct foo {
  void(*xf)(void);
  int r;
} sFoo;

void func(void) {
  sFoo.xf = func; /* <-- like this */
}

int main()
{
  func();
  printf("FuncPtr  is: %p\n", sFoo.xf);
  printf("FuncAddr is: %p\n", &func);
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

I can't think of a reason why this shouldn't work portably, but that doesn't mean there isn't one. I've tested it with MinGW and MSVC on Windows, and gcc on Ubuntu, and it works fine. The C standard is pretty much silent, except to say that (C99 5.1.1.2) function references are resolved in the final translation phase.

My main aggravation is that I can't find anything that *confirms* that this is standard behavior. I've run across comments in the past that said that you *couldn't* take the address of a function from within that function, which I thought were bogus at the time, but didn't really have the time or inclination to actually check it out, until now.

Comment: Notice, that printing function pointer with `%p` is undefined behavior. There's no format specifier to print function pointers.

Comment: The address-of and pointer dereference operators don't really do anything to functions, so `func`, `&func` and `*func` are all the same thing (where `func` is a function). The use of `%p` to print anything other than a `void *` is non-standard. Converting a function pointer to `void *` is technically UB too.

Comment: It works.  The function is known to be a function; its name therefore is a pointer to the function

Comment: with `%p` we can print any pointers. no matter to where it point and which it type

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there any reason you can't take the address of a function from within that function?

Nope.

> The C standard is pretty much silent, except to say that (C99 5.1.1.2) function references are resolved in the final translation phase.

The standard is not silent; it just does not address that particular case *explicitly*.  It is not a special case.

> My main aggravation is that I can't find anything that confirms that this is standard behavior.

The standard specifies that you can obtain the address of a function, and it describes how.  It makes no exception for code inside the function's definition, so the general rules apply there.  It would in fact be pretty inconsistent if you could not obtain a pointer to a function within that function's implementation, since you can certainly *call* it from there (*i.e.* recursively).

> I've run across comments in the past that said that you couldn't take the address of a function from within that function, which I thought were bogus at the time, but didn't really have the time or inclination to actually check it out, until now.

I'm inclined to agree that such comments were mistaken to whatever extent they were directed at standard C.  Perhaps, though, they were directed at some non-conforming implementation.  Or perhaps you misremember.  Obviously, I cannot address any such comments with specificity unless you provide a reference, and preferrably an in-context quotation in your question.

Answer (score 2):

The only constraints on the unary `&` operator are as follows:

> The operand of the unary & operator shall be either a function designator, the result of a [] or unary * operator, or an lvalue that
>   designates an object that is not a bit-field and is not declared with
>   the register storage-class specifier.

Functions identifiers satisfy this (perhaps counter-intuitively, a function identifier is an lvalue as per [6.3.2.1p1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p1)), and so it is always legal to take their address.

In fact, if it were illegal, recursive functions would be impossible, because to call a function, you need to use its designator, and [6.3.2.1p4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p4) defines such use in terms of a conversion to a function pointer:

> A function designator is an expression that has function type. Except
>   when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the _Alignof
>   operator,65) or the unary & operator, a function designator with type
>   ''function returning type'' is converted to an expression that has
>   type ''pointer to function returning type''.